# Is there any research into the number of people that Accept cookies via a GDPR compliant banner?

Tags: cookies, gdpr

Haven't been able to find much info so far and though this would be a good place to ask...

Two aspects to this question:

1. Is there any research into the rates of Accepting all cookies via a GDPR compliant banner (and this could also include the rates of choosing to customise the cookies you accept, as well as users who do not engage with the banner at all)
2. Is there any related research about compliant UI practices that encourage acceptance, and the extent to which this makes a difference.

Hope there is some solid data out there.

Answer (score 2):

Some leads:

- [(Un)informed Consent: Studying GDPR Consent Notices in the Field](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.02638.pdf)
- [Multiple Purposes, Multiple Problems: A User Study of Consent Dialogs after GDPR](https://content.sciendo.com/view/journals/popets/2020/2/article-p481.xml)
- [Consent notices and cognitive cost after the GDPR : an experimental study](https://repositorio.ucp.pt/handle/10400.14/31285)

[Google Scholar is your friend](https://scholar.google.com/)